# Disable/Enable selection based on row content of PrimeNG TurboTable or TreeTable

Tags: angular, primeng-turbotable, primeng-treetable

With p-treeTable i can enable selection for all rows, based on selectionMode = "single". Now i'd like to disable selection for rows, which are not intended to be selected.

PrimeNG 7, Angular 7.

If I remove `[ttRow]="rowNode" [ttSelectableRow]="rowNode"` of tr's body template, all rows are not selectable.

```
<p-treeTable [value]="nodes" [columns]="columns" selectionMode="single" 
[(selection)]="selectedNode" dataKey="id" >

...

   <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowNode let-rowData="rowData" let-columns="columns">
      <tr [ttRow]="rowNode" [ttSelectableRow]="rowNode">
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">            
          {{ rowData[col.field] }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-treeTable>
```

Now i need a check based on the row data, e.g. `rowData.selectable', to enable/disable row selection based on the outcome of`rowData.selectable`.
Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's what ttSelectableRowDisabled is for. It seems to do the job anyway.

```
<tr [ttRow]="rowNode" [ttSelectableRow]="rowNode" 
    [ttSelectableRowDisabled]=!rowData.selectable>
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns">            
        {{ rowData[col.field] }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question.
But how about something like:

```
<tr [ttRow]="rowNode" [ttSelectableRow]="rowNode" *ngIf=rowData.selectable>
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns">            
      {{ rowData[col.field] }}
    </td>
</tr>

<tr [ttRow]="rowNode" *ngIf=!rowData.selectable>
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns">            
      {{ rowData[col.field] }}
    </td>
</tr>
```